# Angular2 OpenIddict and Authorizing Roles in AspNetCore WebApi

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-middleware

I am currently attempting to add Roles to my Angular2 AspNetCore WebApi sample application, which may be found here: https://github.com/tonywr71/Snazzle

Unfortunately, I'm a bit stuck. I have successfully implemented ASOS authentication. The token is returned from the connect/token method, and I can call my custom method with the bearer token in the header, and it will successfully authorize.

Now there are two issues remaining. One is that even though it authorizes, the Name field in the User.Identity object is not set. I got around this by adding username to Claims. And secondly, I want the Roles to be populated so I can use Roles in the Authorize attribute. I have enabled Asp.Net Core Identity in the Startup.cs file, and have configured database. So I would really like to be able to put an Authorize attribute on the webapi method and set the Roles allowed in that attribute.

Any idea how to get it to populate the Name and Roles?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Any idea how to get it to populate the Name and Roles?

To get the username, you must request the standard `profile` scope. For the roles, add `roles`.

E.g:

```
grant_type=password&username=johndoe&password=A3ddj3w&scope=openid%20profile%20roles
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems to work. It does seem to violate some sort of security principles by authorising against roles that have been submitted from the client. This is why I initially overlooked this. Is there some reason they had to do it that way?

Comment: Roles are not "submitted" by the client. The "roles" scope is only there to allow OpenIddict to return (and disclose) them in both the access and the identity token. Since the identity token is readable by the client application (and so does the access token if it's a JWT), there's a risk of data exposure and that's why an additional scope is used to ensure the developer is aware of this fact.

Comment: I'm still a little confused here. If I don't add the "roles" scope, then the Roles property of the Authorize attribute will not be recognised and nothing will successfully authorise. It seems a bit odd to me that to get Roles to Authorize on the Server, I have to submit the "roles" scope from the client. And if I put the "roles" scope on the client request, then the list of roles will also be sent to the client. Is this the case?

Comment: That's how it works and there's a reason for that: if you opt for JWT access tokens (which is quite frequent), they can be read by everyone - including the client application - since they are not encrypted. If we always included the roles in the access tokens independently of the "roles" scope, there would be a risk of private data leakage (roles are often confidential and shouldn't be readable by client apps without explicit consent). Note that it's generally up to the client app' to ensure that the scopes it needs are associated with the received access token.

Comment: Note that nothing forces you to use this default behavior: you're even encouraged to manually select the scopes you want to grant. Replace `request.GetScopes()` by the list of scopes you need: https://github.com/openiddict/openiddict-core/blob/dev/samples/Mvc.Server/Controllers/AuthorizationController.cs#L171 and https://github.com/openiddict/openiddict-core/blob/dev/samples/Mvc.Server/Controllers/AuthorizationController.cs#L180